# Why am I getting the opposite of what is true in List<Char>.Contains(char)

Tags: c#, linq, list, char, utf

I have tested this in two applications; Where I pass in a char looking for a special character.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo entered = Console.ReadKey();
            char asChar = Convert.ToChar(entered.KeyChar);
            Console.WriteLine(IsSpecialChar(asChar));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string IsSpecialChar(char dWord)
        {
            List<char> Special = new List<char>();

            System.Globalization.NumberStyles hexer = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber;
            Special.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((int.Parse("21", hexer)), int.Parse("2f", hexer)).Select(x => Convert.ToChar(x)));
            Special.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((int.Parse("3a", hexer)), int.Parse("40", hexer)).Select(x => Convert.ToChar(x)));
            Special.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((int.Parse("5c", hexer)), int.Parse("60", hexer)).Select(x => Convert.ToChar(x)));
            Special.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((int.Parse("7e", hexer)), int.Parse("7e", hexer)).Select(x => Convert.ToChar(x)));

            if (Special.Contains(Convert.ToChar(dWord)))
            {
                return "Special";
            }
            else return "NA";
        }
```

For some reason the Special.Contains always sees the opposite of what is true.

Some of the characters that are populated are:

```
U+003F  ?   3f  QUESTION MARK
U+0040  @   40  COMMERCIAL AT
U+0041  A   41  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
U+0042  B   42  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
```

Letters A and B should not be there. What is going on?

Comment: With the changes necessary as told by Servy: http://ideone.com/WyCBbI

Comment: Thanks, @xanatos , as soon as I read Servy's answer it was a giant face palm and 2 seconds of work to fix! Days like this I get a bloody forehead from banging it on my desk in disbelief I did that!

Comment: Next time, breakpoint on the `if`, then you look at Special and you see that there are too many items there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enumerable.Range accepts a start of the range **and the length of the range** rather than a start of the range and an *end of the range*.

Because of this, your ranges aren't at all what you intended them to be.